# Centos systemctl startup script - Ruby bad interpreter

Tags: bash, shell, path, centos7

I'm getting the following error when systemctl attempts to run my startup script

```
/usr/bin/startup/status_start.sh: /usr/local/bin/procodile: /usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Here's my start script

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
cd /opt/staytus/staytus/
procodile start
```

Now I assume this has something to do with the bash shell and PATH's etc but I don't really understand that world :)

I have tried my start script with both #!/usr/bin/bash and #!/bin/bash

Any other suggestions?

---

### UPDATE 1:

added a line to my script to print out 'which ruby' which resulted in the following error

```
Oct 06 17:31:02 status.sh[11014]: which: no ruby in (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin)
```

which lead me to add more

```
echo "current path:" $PATH
PATH=/opt/staytus/.rbenv/shims/ruby:$PATH
echo "new path:" $PATH
```

BUT despite my attempts I still get errors when systemctl runs start...

```
Oct 06 17:45:37 start.sh[2878]: current path: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
Oct 06 17:45:37 start.sh[2878]: new path: /opt/staytus/.rbenv/shims/ruby:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
Oct 06 17:45:37 start.sh[2878]: /usr/bin/startup/start.sh: /usr/local/bin/procodile: /usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

### Update 2

here's the systemctl script

```
[Unit]
Description=Starts up procodile which runs staytus

[Service]
User=staytus
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/opt/staytus/staytus/
ExecStart=/usr/bin/startup/start.sh
ExecStop=/usr/bin/startup/stop.sh
# Restart=on-abort

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When running version as root, staytus

```
bash: /usr/bin/ruby: No such file or directory
```

Ruby appears to be installed in

```
which ruby
~/.rbenv/shims/ruby
```

### UPDATE 3:

OK so I decided to add what appeared to be missing path flows into my script by another script that prints the command to set the environment via the eval command

path.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
echo export PATH=/opt/staytus/bin/procodile:/opt/staytus/.rbenv/shims/ruby:/usr/lib64/ruby:/usr/share/ruby:/usr/bin/bash:$PATH
```

start.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -xv
whoami
echo "current path:" $PATH
cd /opt/staytus/staytus/
pwd
eval `/usr/bin/startup/path.sh`
echo "New path:" $PATH
procodile start
```

Comment: isntall ruby on your system then, it's not installed. procodile is written in ruby

Comment: Ruby is installed - the script runs fine alone it’s just a systemctl thing

Comment: Can you post systemctl service file? Can you just run `/usr/bin/ruby --version` as the ExecStart from systemctl service file? What if you run `/usr/bin/ruby --version` from inside your script file? Is you ruby installed in /usr/bin/ruby? Is it a symlink? What if you do `ruby procodile start` from the script?

Comment: Updated details - strange running the script directly works but ruby procodile start does not but  procodile start alone does.... ? seems to be similar with procodile .... which procodile
/opt/staytus/.rbenv/shims/procodile

Comment: I suspect `head -n 1 $(which procodile)` will show you the problem, this program is expecting to find ruby somewhere and it's not. If you want this to run as a system service you really should install ruby in a proper location, i.e. in `/usr/bin`.

Comment: hmm interesting command...
head -n 1 $(which procodile)
#!/usr/bin/env bash

does that mean my shell script needs to start with that ? or I need to put that in my path within my script?

Comment: still running into the same issues here... anyone have advice?

Comment: added update 3 with current thiking and changes but still no luck

Comment: Please don't try to solve problems by adding `eval` without a specific and compelling reason to do so -- it's much more likely to make things *worse* (or, worse, to make things subtly insecure).

Answer (score 0):

One of your scripts -- probably `/usr/local/bin/procodile`, but potentially something it invokes -- starts with `#!/usr/bin/ruby`.

However, your Ruby interpreter *isn't installed* as `/usr/bin/ruby`, so that breaks.

Find the responsible script, and change its first line to `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`, which will honor the PATH for finding the interpreter to run with.